# Laravel Livewire checkbox show "Attempt to read property "..." on array"

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i dont seem to find the question that match my case so i'm just gonna make one.

My problem is when i make an index page show all record of the DataBase with checkbox, the moment i click the checkbox, it shows an erorr like this "Attempt to read property "id" on array"

My component is like this:

```
class ProductCheckbox extends Component
{   
    public $data;
    public $selectedProduct = [];

    public function render()
    {    
        return view('livewire.product-checkbox');
    }
}
```

And my view is like this:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>   
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($data as $product)
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $product->id }}" wire:model="selectedProduct">
                </td>

                <td> {{ $product->name }} </td>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Although when i check $selectedProduct, there is already value in it when i click the checkbox, but it still show the error box "Attempt to read property "id" on array", and it point the error right at the "<input type="checkbox" value="{{ $product->id }} wire:model="selectedProduct">"

Please help, i am seriously got no clue what happen here :(

Comment: Is `$property` an `object`, or an `array`?

Comment: i'm not sure what are you asking, but $product is an object, that's why i use {{ $product->id }}, and "id" is just a sole integer type variable, "id" is not an object

Comment: I ask as that is the only thing in your code that tries to access anything related to `id`. Might be worth just checking it is definately an `object`.

Comment: i use dd(), and even var_dump() on "$product->id", it show "int(*number*)"

Comment: Is there any other code then you have not included?

Comment: not quite much, the $data is just an array which contain objects, just normal DB data you get from a "get()" query, aside that there are lots of JS and CSS i included, but i have test not using them and still got an error above

Comment: There is something missing then as the code in your question works fine in isolation.

Comment: I got it, there are 2 things that got me wrong:
1. The $data i use is fetch from the normal controller like this: @livewire('product-checkbox', ['data' => $data]) ======> This somehow trigger the error all the time, i have to use query inside the livewire component itself, and guess what, no more error anymore.
2. I have to use <form></form> to cover the whole <table> in order for it to actually work